# Building an infinite set $A\subseteq\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $\forall a\in A,(a^2+1\mid a!)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'd like to build this infinite set (Or an infinite subset of it):

$$A=\{a\in\mathbb{Z}^+\mid a^2+1\mid a!\}$$

How could I do it?

I've seen that $18\in A$. How could I build, with some element $a_k$, an element $a_{k+1}>a_k$ which lies in $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, set $a_n=2(20n+3)^2=800n^2+240n+18$.  It turns out that we may factor $$a_n^2+1=5(800n^2+200n+13)(160n^2+56n+5)$$
These three terms are each seen to be less than $a_n$, and distinct, so their product divides $a_n!$.

---

How did I come up with this?  First, I found a second element of $A$, namely $242=2\cdot 11^2$.  The first element was $18=2\cdot 3^2$.  These seem to be in a pattern; it turns out that $(2\cdot(4k+3)^2)^2+1$ factors, with one factor already small enough.  The other factor is a bit too large, so I had to choose $k$ carefully so that it is always a multiple of $5$.